# Ionic + Capacitor app : there is no way to make it work

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm following [this tutorial](https://devdactic.com/sqlite-ionic-app-with-capacitor) in order to create a basic Ionic + Capacitor SQLite app. I installed Ionic according to the indications on the website for the last version, but while trying to run the app it refused because of the NodeJS version. Finally solved it and after installing Android Studio + SDK I finally got to run the blank app. Now I'm trying to follow the instructions on that tutorial in order to add SQLite to my app, but when I create the database service it gives me error like:

```
private async setupDatabase() {
const dbSetupDone = await Storage.get({ key: DB_SETUP_KEY });

if (!dbSetupDone.value) {
  this.downloadDatabase();
} else {
  this.dbName = (await Storage.get({ key: DB_NAME_KEY })).value;
  await CapacitorSQLite.open({ database: this.dbName });
  this.dbReady.next(true);
}
```

}

**"*Property 'get' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['get'].*"**

I see a lot of similar errors. The tutorial is from 2020, has so much changed in Ionic that nothing works after four years? Am I using the wrong documentation and related sites?

Answer (score -1):

which capacitor version are you at?

The Capacitor Storage plugin changed its name to Preferences. Your issue might related to that.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/preferences

Comment: Version 5.6.0.   This is a real mess, I am now trying (following step by step) to archive the same following this tutorial https://www.positronx.io/ionic-sqlite-database-crud-app-example-tutorial/#tc_8652_01  and it fails, ionic won't compile. Frustrating.

Comment: Understood. Note that given tutorial is using Cordova, while most plugins are compatible with Capacitor, you might need to change native files to make them work.

Since you have blank application ready, you can implement plugins by referring to the latest version:
https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/preferences

Also, there is a updated demo mentioned in the repo:
https://github.com/jepiqueau/blog-tutorials-apps/tree/main/SQLite/Part-1/ionic7-angular-sqlite-app

Comment: Now it says it can't find the SQLite plugin (which is installed following the reccomended instructions carefully) ... this is beyond ridiculous , I don't understand how they can offer such a bad product.